# Deeplinks with Backbone frontend on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mod-rewrite, backbone.js

I have a one page javascript(Backbone) frontend running on S3 and I'd like to have a couple of deeplinks to be redirected to the same index file. You'd normally do this with mod_rewrite in Apache but there is no way to do this in S3.

I have tried setting the default error document to be the same as the index document, and 
this works on the surface, but if you check the actual response status header you'll see the page comes back as a 404. This is obviously not good.

There is another solution, its ugly but better than the error document hack:

It turns out that you can create a copy of index.html and name it simply the same as the subdirectory(minus the trailing slash), so for example if I clone index.html and name it 'about', and make sure the Content-Type is set to text/html (in the metadata tab) all requests to /about will return the new 'about' which is a copy of index.html.

Obviously this solution is sub-optimal and only works with predefined deeplink targets, but the hassle could be lessened if the step to clone index.html was part of a build process for the frontend. Using Backbone-Boilerplate I could write a grunt task to do just that.

Other than these 2 hacky workarounds I dont see a way of doing this other than resorting to hashbangs..

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

---

UPDATE:

S3 now (for a while actually) supports [Index Documents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html) which solves this problem.

Also if you use Route 53 for your DNS management you can set up an [alias record](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingAliasRRSets.html) pointing to your S3 bucket, so you dont need a subdomain+cname anymore :)

Comment: Hey, how does Index Documents solve your problem? If I access some URL  and the file isn't there I am supposed to serve using index.html. A rerouting condition can be created which says redirect when 404, but in the redirect rule we can't mention an IndexDocument.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately as far as I know (and I use s3 websites quite a bit) you're right on the money. The 404 hack is a really bad idea as you said, and so you basically have these options:

- Use a regular backend of some kind and not S3
- The `Content-Type` work-around
- Hashbangs

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news :)

For me, the fact that you can't really direct the root of the domain to S3 websites was the deal breaker for some of my stuff. `mod_rewrite`-type scenarios sounds like another good example where it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try redirecting to hash? I am not sure if this S3 feature was available when you asked this question, but I was able to fix the problem using these redirection rules in static web hosting section of folder's properties.

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>topic/</KeyPrefixEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>#topic/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

The rest is handled in Backbone.js application.

Comment: I did mention in the last paragraph that I didn't want to resort to that. Fortunately S3 now supports Index Documents which solves the problem :)